# Get all IP adresses on LAN

Tags: c#

I have a program that  ping and take all the ip address that are active in a LAN  i code it with csharp console mode the problem is that when  I put it in mode form  an error appear in Spinwatch and a error message box appear

Here is the code and error below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;

namespace pingagediffusiontest
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
       public Form1()
         {
           InitializeComponent();
         }



       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }
      private static List<Ping> pingers = new List<Ping>();
      private static int instances = 0;

    private static object @lock = new object();

   private static int result = 0;
    private static int timeOut = 250;

    private static int ttl = 5;

    static void Mains()
  {
     string baseIP = "192.168.1.";

    Console.WriteLine("Pinging 255 destinations of D-class in {0}*", baseIP);

    CreatePingers(255);


        PingOptions po = new PingOptions(ttl, true);
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data= enc.GetBytes("abababababababababababababababab");

      SpinWait wait = new SpinWait();
        int cnt = 1;

      Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        foreach (Ping p in pingers) {
            lock (@lock) {
            instances += 1;
            }

            p.SendAsync(string.Concat(baseIP, cnt.ToString()), timeOut, data, po);
            cnt += 1;
        }

        while (instances > 0) {
            wait.SpinOnce();
        }

        watch.Stop();

    DestroyPingers();
 Console.WriteLine("Finished in {0}. Found {1} active IP-addresses.",     watch.Elapsed.ToString(), result);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static void Ping_completed(object s, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (@lock) {
            instances -= 1;
        }

        if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Active IP: ", e.Reply.Address.ToString()));
            result += 1;
        } else {
           Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Non-active IP: ", e.Reply.Address.ToString()))
        }
    }


    private static void CreatePingers(int cnt)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++) {
            Ping p = new Ping();
            p.PingCompleted += Ping_completed;
            pingers.Add(p);
        }
    }

    private static void DestroyPingers()
    {
        foreach (Ping p in pingers) {
            p.PingCompleted -= Ping_completed;
            p.Dispose();
        }

        pingers.Clear();

    }
    }

}
```

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'SpinWait' could not be found 
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'Stopwatch' could not be found 
Error   4   The name 'Stopwatch' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Add a semicolon (`;`) to the end of the `Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Non-active IP: "))` line and add a `using System.Diagnostics;` at the top, as that is `Stopwatch`'s namespace. You can see this by hovering the erroneous line, clicking the little arrow and looking at the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

At the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

> Error 3 The type or namespace name 'Stopwatch' could not be found

You need to import following namespace to use `StopWatch` in your program:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

as suggested by `@CodeCaster` in comments - you are missing `semicolon` to terminate the `Console.WriteLine()` statement :

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Non-active IP: ", e.Reply.Address.ToString()))  //missing semicolon
```

**Suggestion :** as you have stated you converted code from Console Application to Windows Forms Application it would be nice if you can change/replace all `Console.WriteLine()` Statements with `MessageBox.Show()` as shown below:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Non-active IP: ", e.Reply.Address.ToString()));
```